# Adding the video field to a content type

Tags: 6, entities, files

We've been using an SWF player for a while. I added the Video module without adding a new content type, just to see if the HTML5 tag worked. It does. However, that obviously doesn't give us an SWF fallback.

I then tried to add a Video content type as per [this video tutorial](http://www.modulesunraveled.com/video/part-4-create-video-content-type), but when I did it, I didn't see the Video field type or an option for 'video-widget'. Is that a feature present only in Drupal 7, or did I miss something in configuring the Video module?

How do I enable the Video widget so I can have HTML5 **and** the SWF fallback? Is there an alternative set of HTML to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, then I realized that we were doing it the wrong way.

You have to select "file" drop down "Select a Field Type", then "Video" becomes available in the next drop down labelled "Form element to edit the data".

Comment: I've removed the spam link, please don't do it again